# Access jQuery object inside a function bound to another object

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, object, bind

```
var obj = {
    someFunction : function() {
        $('#someID').on('change', '#someOtherId', function(e) {
            this.someOtherFunction(); // works fine
        }.bind(this));
    },

    someOtherFunction : function() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

The above piece of code works fine but i am not sure how to access the jQuery wrapped element using `$(this)` inside the `someFunction`. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Either use `$(e.target)` or don't use bind

Comment: use `$(e.currentTarget)`

Comment: is e.target cross browser?

Comment: Yeah, since jQuery normalizes the event object, you can use all the objects in the W3C standards. But if your code needs to be cross-browser, make sure you polyfill `bind` because it's not supported by < IE 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var obj = {
    someFunction : function() {
        var me = this;
        $('#someID').on('change', '#someOtherId', function(e) {
            var $elem = $(this); // element / jquery object
            me.someOtherFunction(); // works fine
            // me is assigned in "obj" scope 
        });
    },

    someOtherFunction : function() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: is this really an efficient way of handling such situation?

Comment: Yes it is. Huge libraries like ExtJS are also using this approach.

Comment: If he wants only callback function? :\

Comment: Sorry by mistake :\ cancelled it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the clean way is to use [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/)

```
var obj = {
    someFunction : function() {
        $('#someID').on('change', '#someOtherId', $.proxy(this.someOtherFunction, this));
    },

    someOtherFunction : function(e) {
        //this is the jquery $(this) element
        var $el = $(e.currentTarget);

        //the "this" is the main "obj" object
    }
}
```

On a anonymous callback function:

```
    var obj = {
        someFunction : function() {
            $('#someID').on('change', '#someOtherId', $.proxy(function (e) {
                //this is the jquery $(this) element
                var $el = $(e.currentTarget);

                //the "this" is the main "obj" object
                this.someOtherFunction();
            }, this));
        },

        someOtherFunction : function(e) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: both.. in different parts, as per requirement.

Comment: Yes your answer is really good but @sjkm's answer can be used anywhere and not just for callbacks.. i tried using your answer within the callback function (closure) but it did not work.

Comment: See above... Don't forget the (e) variable. I think that my both ways are better. I don't do it for you to change the "correct" but you to learn... :)